# How do I generate a URL when not in a controller

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have been developing a system using Symfony2(.3) now and came across an issue... I'm trying to build a form class that is supposed to post to `/register`. How can I do the equivalent of

`$url = $this->generateUrl('register');` or `$this->get('router')->generate('register');`

inside a class that extends AbstractType? Code below.

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->setAction(/*I want the URL generated here*/)
                ->add('username', 'string')
                ->add('password', 'repeated', array(

                ))
                ->add('cellphone', 'text', array(
                    'max_length' => 10,
                    'invalid_message' => 'A phone number must be exactly 10 characters long',
                ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\MainBundle\Entity\SystemUser',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

Am I just missing the point here? Am I not supposed to do this? I can't find anything useful on Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the `router` service into your `RegistrationFormType`.

Add this to your Type,

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{    
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
       $this->router = $router;
    }
    // ...
```

Then, if you've defined your type as a service, your should build it as follow (by providing @router service as an argument to the constructor),

```
services:
    form.type.user_registration:
        class: path_to_your_type/RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [ @router ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

You may then be able to access the [router's generate helper](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_generate) in your Type by calling,

```
$this->router->generate('register');
```

**Also**, in order to build your Type through the [Dependency Injection Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html), you'll have to use,

```
$form = $this->createForm('user_registration', $systemUserInstance);
```

instead of,

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationFormType(), $systemUserInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to hit Add Comment to ask you about that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a **service**, or a **form type as a service** you can pass the router as parameter

```
acme.my_service:
    class: %acme.my_service.class%
    arguments: [ @router ]
```

then add it in your constructor

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class MyService
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
...
}
```

then you can generate your url by using $this->router->generateUrl(...

It should work the same for form type